# Re make multiple line to paragraph in objective c

Tags: objective-c, regex

i have this 2 paragraphs like this

```
On Friday afternoon after you leave work, you probably
think about going out and having a few drinks with 
friends to relax and wind down.  Even though you 
may think you deserve to go out and have a few drinks,
there are some things that you should certainly keep
in mind.

Like any other day, tomorrow is going to be a day
for exercise, and since you are exercising on a 
regular basis, a few drinks of alcohol won't really
hurt anything, right?  Before you decide to rush out
to the local bar, there are a few things below that
you should think about before you make your choice
about going out to drink some alcohol.
```

How can i format to this:

```
On Friday afternoon after you leave work, you probably think about going out and having a few drinks with friends to relax and wind down. Even though you may think you deserve to go out and have a few drinks, there are some things that you should certainly keep in mind.

Like any other day, tomorrow is going to be a day for exercise, and since you are exercising on a regular basis, a few drinks of alcohol won't really hurt anything, right? Before you decide to rush out to the local bar, there are a few things below that you should think about before you make your choice about going out to drink some alcohol.
```

I only know how to replace \n with space like this:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "
```

But i dont know how to recognize each paragraph

Thanks you

Comment: Each paragraph is separated by 2 (or more) newlines...

Comment: You could have tried harder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code isn't bulletproof and additional code is needed to clean up any extraneous newline characters, but it should serve to start you off:

```
// Assuming your input string contains all the text, then:

NSArray *paragraphs = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"];
for (NSString *paragraph in paragraphs)
{
    NSString *cleaned = [paragraph stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"paragraph = %@", cleaned);
}
```

Comment: You should also be looking for two (or more) newlines separated by white space. Possibly also only one newline followed by white space. Sometimes there's no blank line(s) between paragraphs, and the beginning of a new paragraph is indicated only by indentation of the first line.

Comment: @Caleb Agreed; the code falls short in many respects, but I am not inclined to write a complete solution at the moment (CBA).

Comment: could you please show us the complete solution ? btw, you have the typo: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not tringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString . Thanks

Comment: in my case each paragraph is separated by \r\n\r\n . Thanks

Comment: @trojanfoe Right -- when I said 'you' I was really thinking of the OP, as in "hey OP, you should also consider...". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Search for two consecutive "\n\n". This will tell you it's a paragraph.